# Contact Form 7 to featured image

Tags: wp-insert-post, plugin-contact-form-7

I am trying to retrieve a file uploaded in the front-end with contact form 7 and assign it to a featured image custom post type. Heres is my code so far :

```
function form_to_post( $posted_data ) {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'projects',
        'post_status'=> 'draft',
        'post_title'=> wp_strip_all_tags( $posted_data['title'] ),
        'post_content'=> wp_strip_all_tags( $posted_data['pitch'] ),
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($args);

    if( ! is_wp_error( $post_id ) ) {

        if( isset($posted_data['featured']) ){
            $featuredUpload = wp_upload_bits($posted_data['featured']['name'], null, file_get_contents($posted_data['featured']['tmp_name']));

            $filename = $featuredUpload['file'];
            $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
            $attachment = array(
                'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                'post_parent' => $post_id,
                'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_status' => 'inherit'
            );
            $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $post_id );

            if (!is_wp_error($attachment_id)) {
                require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
                $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $filename );
                wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id,  $attachment_data );
                set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attachment_id );
            }
        }
    }

    return $posted_data;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_posted_data', 'form_to_post' );
```

The `error_log` shows 1 as the value of `$posted_data['featured']` so that means the file datas are not stored in this variable. I've looked at the [Contact Form 7 doc](https://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/) and they say that the file is moved to a temporary  directory (wp-content/uploads/wpcf7_uploads) before the mail is sent. So does anyone know how to get the file datas?

Thanks

Comment: Why not enable debugging ( DEBUG_LOG ) and use PHPs `error_log()` function to write it to a log. You could `print_r()` the whole posted variable and see what it holds.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee you are right, thank you. So the error_log show 1 as the value of my variable. So the file information is not stored there. I'll modify my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @Judd Franklin for the directions. I was also missing `$submission->uploaded_files();`.

Here is the working code for those who are looking for the same answer:

```
function image_form_to_featured_image( $contact_form ) {

    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

    // Creating a new post with contact form values
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'projects',
        'post_status'=> 'draft',
        'post_title'=> wp_strip_all_tags( $posted_data['title'] ),
        'post_content'=> wp_strip_all_tags( $posted_data['pitch'] ),
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($args);

    // Retrieving and inserting uploaded image as featured image
    $uploadedFiles = $submission->uploaded_files();

    if( isset($posted_data['featured']) ){
        $featuredUpload = wp_upload_bits($posted_data['featured'], null, file_get_contents($uploadedFiles['featured']));


        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
        $filename = $featuredUpload['file'];
        $attachment = array(
            'post_mime_type' => $featuredUpload['type'],
            'post_parent' => $post_id,
            'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'inherit'
        );

        $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $post_id );

        if (!is_wp_error($attachment_id)) {
            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
            $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $filename );
            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id,  $attachment_data );
            set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attachment_id );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'image_form_to_featured_image' );
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the filter you are hooking onto doesn't have access to the post data.

If you use the `wpcf7_before_send_mail` action, and then access the Submission instance data, you get access to the filename of the attachment.

```
function form_to_post( $posted_data ) {
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($args);
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $postData = $submission->get_posted_data();
    die(var_dump($postData["featured"]));

}
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'form_to_post' );
```

This worked for me locally. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Contact form 7 removed file from temporary directory (wp-content/uploads/wpcf7_uploads) after the mail is sent. That's why we need to make a copy of that file in server.

```
 function image_form_to_featured_image( $contact_form ) {

$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
$posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();


// Creating a new post with contact form values
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status'=> 'draft',
    'post_title'=> wp_strip_all_tags( $posted_data['title'] ),
    'post_content'=> wp_strip_all_tags( $posted_data['content'] ),
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post($args);

// Retrieving and inserting uploaded image as featured image
$uploadedFiles = $submission->uploaded_files();

if( isset($uploadedFiles['image']) ){
    $featuredUpload = wp_upload_bits($uploadedFiles['image'], null, file_get_contents($uploadedFiles['image']));


    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
    
    $dataimg= $uploadedFiles['image'];
    $dataFile = $dataimg['0'];
    $filename = basename($dataFile);
    
    $copy_path = '/home/server_user/public_html/wp-content/uploads/new_upload_folder/'.$filename;
    // Copy image to other folder in server
copy($dataFile,$copy_path);
    
    $feature_img = '/home/server_user/public_html/wp-content/uploads/new_upload_folder/'.$filename;
    

    // Check the type of file. We'll use this as the 'post_mime_type'.
    $filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );

    // Get the path to the upload directory.
    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

    // Prepare an array of post data for the attachment.
    $attachment = array(
        'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/new_upload_folder/' . basename( $feature_img ), 
        'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
        'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $feature_img ) ),
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit'
    );

    // Insert the attachment.
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $feature_img, $post_id );

    // Make sure that this file is included, as wp_generate_attachment_metadata() depends on it.
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

    // Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $feature_img );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

    set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
    
  }
}
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'image_form_to_featured_image' );
```